# Order by in Postgresql to sort IP address?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ip-address, sql-order-by

I wish to sort a list of IP address.

Is there any function in Postgresql to use with the order by like INET_ATON in MySql ?

My current IP is on string format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can order your IP address column  `IP_Address` with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY inet(IP_Address)
```

See the [documnetation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html) for further reference.

**Edit:**

This is actually not a function but a type cast to the postgres integrated type for IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar with IPv4 addresses stored as integers in a table, and was able
to use the `'0.0.0.0'::inet + num` trick.

So where `devaddr` is a column in a table `interface` I did:

```
select  distinct ('0.0.0.0'::inet + devaddr) as addr from interface order by addr;
```